# Find the degree of B-Tree to store number of keys?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, b-tree

Suppose you are storing 32 bits keys in a B-tree and each block in the hard disk contains 1024 bits. What is the best value for the degree d of the B-tree?

Comment: Have you made *any* attempt at solving this yourself?

Comment: I tried to solve but I can't do solve this. Can you help me?

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Comment: each key is of 32 bits and memory is 1024 bits. So, 32 keys can be stored. And also block can store d-1 keys. But here keys are 32 so degree may be 33. What do you think?

Comment: What is *d*?  And how does the number of keys you can store relate to the degree?